# Plotting a Property Graph in the most quick and convenient way

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs, database

I have to plot some property graph data in LaTeX. When I try to do this task in LaTeX with TiKz, it usually takes me a lot of time, because I always have to
decide which is the best position of the nodes, and I have no pre-built graph layout to use. Secondly, I would like that such graph layout would adapt to the informations that are contained in each node so that two nodes do not overlap due to the huge information content. Last but not least, I would like to automatically assign to each node and edge a specific color in order to distinguish them by label value. Is there a way to automate such process? When I have to provide a lot of examples, the process of both defining the vertices and alignign them takes me too much time. Thanks in advance.

A final desired representation:
[image]

Comment: I suspect laying things out will be quite difficult.  But partly it will depend on the maximum number of nodes, and the maximum number of connections between them.  If you cap things at 5 nodes and 8 connections, it's not too bad.  If you want to go arbitrarily big, things will get bad quickly.

Comment: Indeed. Since I have to mainly plot examples for research papers, I don't think I will ever have more than a dozen of vertices and arcs whatsoever. It's not a data visualization problem, but only a way to automate part of the TikZ writing process.

Comment: Using `graphdrawing` and `\usegdlibrary` together with `LuaTeX`, you can try to chose an automated graph layout. See **Part IV** on _Graph Drawing_ in the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly a template, but I think this could help you.

To position the nodes automatically without overlapping, you may use a matrix.

Some `pic`s with some `args` may speed your work.

Here an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
    pics/myrec/.style n args={7}{code={%  
        \node (#1) at (0,0) [draw,#2,text=black,font=\tiny, align=center,thick,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm, rounded corners,label={\tiny\{#3,#4\}}]{\textsc{Title=}\textit{#5}\\  \textsc{1Author=}\textit{#6}\\ \textsc{Name=}\textit{#7}};
    }},
    pics/myfc/.style n args={5}{code={% 
    \draw[->, red, dotted] (#1) to[bend left=#3] node[midway,font=\tiny,rotate=#4,#5] {\{Follows,Cites\}} (#2);  
    }},
   pics/myf/.style n args={5}{code={% 
    \draw[->, orange] (#1) to[bend right=#3] node[midway,font=\tiny, rotate=#4,#5] {\{Follows\}} (#2);
     }},
   pics/myc/.style n args={5}{code={% 
  \draw[->, red] (#1) to[bend left=#3] node[midway,font=\tiny, rotate=#4,#5] {\{Cites\}} (#2);
      }},
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[row sep=1cm,column sep=1.5cm] {
       \pic {myrec={nodea}{blue}{User}{Paper}{Graph}{Alice}{Alice}}; & 
       \pic {myrec={nodeb}{green}{User}{Paper}{Join}{Alice}{Alice}}; & 
       \pic {myrec={nodec}{green}{User}{Paper}{OWL}{Bob}{Bob}}; \\
        & 
        & 
       \\
       \pic {myrec={noded}{red}{User}{Paper}{Projection}{Carl}{Carl}}; &
       & 
       \pic {myrec={nodee}{red}{User}{Paper}{$\mu$-calc}{Dan}{Dan}}; \\
    };    
    \pic {myfc={nodea.north east}{nodec.north west}{40}{0}{above}};
    \pic {myfc={nodeb.south}{noded.north east}{0}{45}{below}};
    \pic {myf={nodea.west}{noded.west}{40}{90}{above}};
    \pic {myf={nodeb.east}{nodec.west}{0}{0}{above}};
    \pic {myf={nodec.east}{nodee.east}{-40}{90}{below}};
    \pic {myf={nodee.south west}{noded.south east}{0}{0}{below}};
    \pic {myc={nodec.south west}{noded.east}{0}{30}{below}}; 
    \pic {myc={noded.south east}{nodee.south west}{-40}{0}{below}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I was thinking more of a Lua-based approach. Part of the solution is to use the matrix layout to avoid vertex collisions, but it does not help when automating the writing of some parts and, besides the matrix layout, it actually looks like the code I used to generate my picture.

Comment: @jackb Sorry, I'm a beginner, I don't know how to create a Lua-based approach, but the `pic`s can be re-utilized in all the pictures of the document.

Comment: Yep, in my case I just used node styles, then macros for automating the data input, but my solution is very similar to yours (that's because I'm a beginner, too). Do not worry, and thanks for your suggestion anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be fast you can also use:

- LaTexDraw for PsTricks: http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/
- or TikzEdt for Tikz: http://www.tikzedt.org/index.html

However if you really want to "automate the process", Timothy provided you with a great solution in the comments.

Comment: Yep, I agree. I'll think of implementing something as he suggested in my spare time (that is not that much).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,rounded corners]
    \node (nw) [text width=3cm] at (-5,3) [rectangle,draw] {\textsc{Title} $=$ \textit{Graphs} \textsc{1Author} $=$ \textit{Alice} \textsc{Name} $=$ \textit{Alice}};
    \node (n)  [text width=3cm] at ( 0,3) [rectangle,draw] {\textsc{Title} $=$ \textit{Join} \textsc{1Author} $=$ \textit{Alice} \textsc{Name} $=$ \textit{Alice}};
    \node (ne) [text width=3cm] at (+5,3) [rectangle,draw] {\textsc{Title} $=$ \textit{Graphs} \textsc{1Author} $=$ \textit{Alice} \textsc{Name} $=$ \textit{Alice}};
    \node (sw) [text width=3cm] at (-5,0) [rectangle,draw] {\textsc{Title} $=$ \textit{Graphs} \textsc{1Author} $=$ \textit{Alice} \textsc{Name} $=$ \textit{Alice}};
    \node (se) [text width=3cm] at (+5,0) [rectangle,draw] {\textsc{Title} $=$ \textit{Graphs} \textsc{1Author} $=$ \textit{Alice} \textsc{Name} $=$ \textit{Alice}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (nw.north) {\{User, Paper\}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (n.north)  {\{User, Paper\}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (ne.north) {\{User, Paper\}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (sw.north) {\{User, Paper\}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (se.north) {\{User, Paper\}};
    \draw[red,-{Latex},dotted,very thick] (n) -- node[below,sloped] {\{Follows, Cities\}} (sw.north east);
    \draw[red,-{Latex},dotted,very thick] (nw.north east) to[bend left] node[above,sloped] {\{Follows, Cities\}} (ne.north west);
    \draw[orange,-{Latex},thick] (nw.south west) to node[below,sloped] {\{Follows\}} (sw.north west);
    \draw[orange,-{Latex},thick] (ne.south east) to node[above,sloped] {\{Follows\}} (se.north east);
    \draw[magenta,-{Latex}] (sw.south east) to[bend right] node[below,sloped] {\{Cities\}} (se.south west);
    \draw[orange,-{Latex}] (se.south west) to node[above,sloped] {\{Follows\}} (sw.south east);
    \draw[orange,-{Latex}] (n.east) to node[above,sloped] {\{Follows\}} (ne.west);
    \draw[magenta,-{Latex}] (ne.south west) to node[below,sloped] {\{Cities\}} (sw.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```